# Extend and override JS class private and public methods

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, ecmascript-5, overriding

In *ES5*, having the definition of a base class that provides a public API:

```js
var Class = function(name) {
    var self = this;
    var name = name;

    return {
        print: function() {
          printDetails();
          return this;
        },
        iAmA: function() {
            console.log('I am an instance of:', self.constructor.name);
        }
    };

    function printDetails() {
        console.log('Name', name);
    };
};
```

How can I:

- **extend it, without instantiate it**

  Is `Child.prototype = Class` without `new` wrong? I just want to define the classes and the inheritance and not instantiate any class yet.
- **override a private method (and make it callable through public method)**

  I want *Child.print()* to call *Child.printDetails()*, instead of *Class.printDetails()*.
- **inherit the Class public api without redeclaring it**

  I can `return new Class(name)` from *Child*, but I won't get my new *Child* methods to be called (*Class* methods are called instead of the overridden ones)
- **add a method to the api without redeclaring it all**

  I don't know if it is possible, but my goal is to inherit as much as possible and define just the additions/variations.

The following is what I came up with, but still I don't like to instantiate a `new Class` just to get the public interface. I would like to specify just eventual new public methods.

```js
var Child = function(name, age) {
    var adult = age > 21 ? true : false;

    //return new Class(name);
    var api = new Class(name);
    api.print = function() {
        printDetails();
        return this;
    }
    return api;

    function printDetails() {
        console.log('Child name', name, 'Adult', adult ? 'Yes' : 'No');
    }
};

Child.prototype = Class;
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;

Child.prototype.printDetails = function() {
    console.log('Child name', name, 'Adult', adult ? 'Yes' : 'No');
}

var cls = new Class('Class');
var chd = new Child('Child', 22);

cls.print();
cls.iAmA();
chd.print();
chd.iAmA();
```

Answer (score 0):

> In ES5, having the definition of a base class

That's not what we would usually call a *class* - which would involve instantiation via `new` and prototype inheritance. It's a function returning an object, a *factory function*.

We can still use [parasitical inheritance](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html) to create new objects with an extended API however.

> How can I extend it, without instantiate it?
>   How can I inherit the Class public api without redeclaring it?

Just declare a new function that returns the same kind of object:

```
function ChildClass(name) {
    return Class(name);
}
```

> Is `Child.prototype = Class` without `new` wrong?

Yes. But it would be wrong with `new` either - we just don't need the prototype here.

> How can I override a private method (and make it callable through public method)

You cannot. Private things stay private to the class they are declared in, they cannot be overridden.

> I want `Child.print()` to call `Child.printDetails()`, instead of `Class.printDetails()`.

You can however overwrite the public `print` method to do something different. You successfully did that in your attempt.

> How can I add a method to the api without redeclaring it all

Add it to the object you return, no need to copy everything to a new object ("redeclaring"):

```
function ChildClass(name, age) {
    var obj = Class(name);
    obj.newMethod = function() { return age; }
    return obj;
}
```

> The following is what I came up with

Yes, your `Child` function is exactly what it should look like (maybe except for the `new` in front of `Class` which you don't need).

However, you should drop all that `prototype` stuff (the three assignments) from your code. Your constructor does not use `this` anywhere and returns an object, so it's ignored anyway.